# play json writes subclass gives ambiguous implicit values error

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, implicits

I'm using the play framework, and have an abstract class:

```
 abstract class Base{...}
```

which has its own implicit JSON writer within the companion object

```
object Base {
   implicit val baseWrites: Writes[Base] = (...)(unlift(Base.unapply))
}
```

I subclass this abstract class:

```
case class SubClass{...}
```

which also has its own implicit JSON writer within its companion object

```
object SubClass {
   implicit val subClassWrites: Writes[SubClass] = (...)(unlift(SubClass.unapply))
}
```

When I try to serialize the subclass object using Json.toJson(SubClass), I get an error:

```
[error]  both value subClassWrites in object SubClass of type => play.api.libs.json.
Writes[models.SubClass]
[error]  and value baseWrites in object Base of type =>        
play.api.libs.json.Writes[models.Base]
[error]  match expected type play.api.libs.json.Writes[models.SubClass]
[error]  Ok(Json.toJson(SubClass.find(id)))
```

Is there any way to remove the ambiguity?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are getting a collision because `Writes` has a contravariant type parameter `A`:

```
trait Writes[-A] extends AnyRef
```

It means that `Writes[Base]` is subclass of `Writes[SubClass]` - you can use `Writes[Base]` where `Writes[SubClass]` is required.

The problem is here:

```
val base: Base = new SubClass(...)
val jsBase = Json.toJson(base)
```

So `Writes[Base]` should be able to serialize an instance of `SubClass`. You could use `ADT` in this case:

```
sealed trait Base
object Base {
  implicit val baseWrites: Writes[Base] = 
    new Writes[Base]{
      def writes(o: Base): JsValue = o match {
        case s: SubClass => SubClass.writes.writes(s)
        case s: SubClass2 => SubClass2.writes.writes(s)
      }
    }
}

case class SubClass(...) extends Base
object SubClass {
  val writes: Writes[SubClass] = (...)(unlift(SubClass.unapply))
}

case class SubClass2(...) extends Base
object SubClass2 {
  val writes: Writes[SubClass2] = (...)(unlift(SubClass2.unapply))
}
```

With `sealed` keyword you'll get a warning in case `match` is  not exhaustive.