# Creating Read[T] and Write[T] for Abstract Class

Tags: java, json, scala, playframework

I'm creating `Reads` and `Writes` for my Java classes to make use of the Play Framework's JSON library.

One of my classes has an **abstract** class field.

**ConcreteObj.java**

```
public class ConcreteObj {

private AbstractObj someField;

public ConcreteObj(AbstractObj someField) {
   this.someField = someField;
}

public AbstractObj getSomeField() { return this.someField };
```

...

**Reads & Writes**

```
  implicit val ConcreteObjReads: Reads[ConcreteObj] =
    (JsPath \ "someField").read[AbstractObj].map{x: AbstractObj => new ConcreteObj(x)}

  implicit val ConcreteObjWrites: Writes[ConcreteObj] =
    (JsPath \ "someField").write[AbstractObj].contramap{x: ConcreteObj => x.getField}
```

However the next step, creating a `Reads[AbstractObj]`, doesn't make sense to me since an abstract class cannot be instantiated.

I suppose that the `Writes[AbstractObj]` would look like:

```
implicit val AbstractObjWrites: Writes[AbstractObj] = 
   (JsPath \ "otherField").write[String].contramap{x: AbstractObj => x.getOtherField}
```

But what about the `Reads[AbstractObj]`?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me either...

Comment: meaning my question? or the answer to it? :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the concrete type is not available until runtime you will have to type check/parse type at runtime. It is possible you can do it with the functional syntax api but I've resorted to actually implementing Reads/Writes/Format for those cases, something along the lines:

```
implicit object Example extends Reads[AbstractThing] {

  def reads(json: JsValue) = {
    // somehow figure out the concrete subclass of AbstractThing
    // based on the json
    (json \ "type").as[String] match {
      case "type1" => Json.fromJson[Concrete1](json)
      case "type2" => Json.fromJson[Concrete2](json)
      case t => JsError(s"Unknown concrete type of AbstractThing: $t") 
    }
  }
}
```

This way you can still create re-usable formats/reads/writes for the concrete types that you can use where you *do* know at compile time what kind of object you are serializing/deserializing.

Answer (score 0):

Since the implementation of `ConcreteObj` will work with any implementation of `AbstractObj` I guess you could do something like this:

```
implicit val ConcreteObjReads: Reads[ConcreteObj] =
  (JsPath \ "someField").read[AbstractObj].map { x: AbstractObj => 
    new ConcreteObj(x)
  }

// I don't know the structure of AbstractObj, but this should give you an idea
implicit val AbstractObjReads: Reads[AbstractObj] = 
  (JsPath \ "field").read[String].map{ s: String => 
    new AbstractObject { 
      val field = s 
    }
  }
```