# Play Scala Read/Write depending on type

Tags: json, scala, playframework

i have trouble dealing with Json reader in play framework 2.3 depending on a class field :

My model :

```
trait Data{
  val id:String
  val type:String
  val creation_date:Date
}

case class Price(
  id:String,
  type:String,
  creation_date:Date,
  amount:Int,
  currency:String) extends Data

case class Weight(
  id:String,
  type:String,
  creation_date:Date,
  value:Int,
  unit_of_measurement:String) extends Data

case class MyObject(
  id:String,
  data:List[Data]
)
```

My problem is : 
How can i read MyObject class and keep all values from Json like :

```
{
  id:"1",data:
    [
      {
        id:"1",
        type:"price",
        creation_date:"2014-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        amount:99,
        currency:"dollar"
      },
      {
        id:"1",
        type:"price",
        creation_date:"2014-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        amount:99,
        currency:"dollar"
      },
      {
        id:"1",
        type:"weight",
        creation_date:"2014-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        value:2,
        unit_of_measurement:"tonne"
      }
    ]
}
```

I tried this :

```
implicit val myObjectReads: Reads[MyObject] = (
  ....
  (__ \ "data").read(Reads.traversableReads[List,Data])
```

But it doesn't work

Many thanks for your help !

MC

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Read\[T\] and Write\[T\] for Abstract Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718075/creating-readt-and-writet-for-abstract-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `orElse` method in the `Reads` trait:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Reads.verifying

val priceReads: Reads[Price] = verifying[Price](_.`type` == "price")(Json.reads[Price])
val weightReads: Reads[Weight] = verifying[Weight](_.`type` == "weight")(Json.reads[Weight])
implicit val dataReads: Reads[Data] = priceReads.map(identity[Data]) orElse weightReads.map(identity[Data])
implicit val myObjectReads: Reads[MyObject] = Json.reads[MyObject]
```

Note that I needed to map the `Reads[Price]` and `Reads[Weight]` to `Reads[Data]` before using `orElse` because `Reads` is not covariant (a `Reads[Price]` is not a `Reads[Data]`). I also added the `verifying` reads to check the type value if both `Price` and `Weight` happened to have the same structure.